# How to make parent-children branch system

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-2015

[Repository](https://github.com/OmegaExtern/GIT-BULLSHIT).

I want to work out this system (but I do not know how):
Every non-master branch to act as a children and the master branch being the parent of all children.
When **I push a new commit to the master branch**, I want all children to **sync**. Sync in a way when there is a new file it gets added into all children, when some file gets deleted it gets deleted from all children, and finally when a shared file gets changed I want to manually resolve it using Visual Studio 2015 environment on Windows machine.
However, when **I push a new commit to the children branch** and if commit **does not** change any of the shared files, then that is property of that specific children and should not get shared with any other branch.

Comment: AFAIK you can use Git to accomplish this but if you really want it automated, you'll have to write a script.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Ok, well how would you do it manually using VS2015?

Comment: This is a big question...do you really want an answer?

Comment: Feel free to post your own answer.